# My code consumes a large number of requests Directions API

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have a taxi app (expo react native) that I use Directions API In the captain screen to go to the customer and show a path, but it consumes a lot of requests in Google Map I just want the track and I don't want it to be a track that gets automatically erased when the captain moves because that takes a lot of requests

This my JS code

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(() => {
    if (pageActive.current && curBooking && lastLocation && (curBooking.status == 'ACCEPTED' || curBooking.status == 'STARTED')) {
      if (lastCoords && lastCoords.lat != lastLocation.lat && lastCoords.lat != lastLocation.lng) {
        if (curBooking.status == 'ACCEPTED') {
          let point1 = {
            lat: lastLocation.lat,
            lng: lastLocation.lng
          };
          let point2 = {
            lat: curBooking.pickup.lat,
            lng: curBooking.pickup.lng
          };
          fitMap(point1, point2);
        } else {
          let point1 = {
            lat: lastLocation.lat,
            lng: lastLocation.lng
          };
          let point2 = {
            lat: curBooking.drop.lat,
            lng: curBooking.drop.lng
          };
          fitMap(point1, point2);
        }
        setlastCoords(lastLocation);
      }
    }
  }, 20000);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if (lastLocation && curBooking && curBooking.status == 'ACCEPTED') {
    let point1 = {
      lat: lastLocation.lat,
      lng: lastLocation.lng
    };
    let point2 = {
      lat: curBooking.pickup.lat,
      lng: curBooking.pickup.lng
    };
    fitMap(point1, point2);
    setlastCoords(lastLocation);
  }

  if (curBooking && curBooking.status == 'ARRIVED') {
    setlastCoords(null);
    setTimeout(() => {
      mapRef.current.fitToCoordinates([{
        latitude: curBooking.pickup.lat,
        longitude: curBooking.pickup.lng
      }, {
        latitude: curBooking.drop.lat,
        longitude: curBooking.drop.lng
      }], {
        edgePadding: {
          top: 40,
          right: 40,
          bottom: 40,
          left: 40
        },
        animated: true,
      })
    }, 1000);
  }
  if (lastLocation && curBooking && curBooking.status == 'STARTED') {
    let point1 = {
      lat: lastLocation.lat,
      lng: lastLocation.lng
    };
    let point2 = {
      lat: curBooking.drop.lat,
      lng: curBooking.drop.lng
    };
    fitMap(point1, point2);
    setlastCoords(lastLocation);
  }
  if (lastLocation && curBooking && curBooking.status == 'REACHED' && role == 'rider') {
    setTimeout(() => {
      mapRef.current.fitToCoordinates([{
        latitude: curBooking.pickup.lat,
        longitude: curBooking.pickup.lng
      }, {
        latitude: lastLocation.lat,
        longitude: lastLocation.lng
      }], {
        edgePadding: {
          top: 40,
          right: 40,
          bottom: 40,
          left: 40
        },
        animated: true,
      })
    }, 1000);
  }
}, [lastLocation, curBooking])

const fitMap = (point1, point2) => {
  let startLoc = '"' + point1.lat + ',' + point1.lng + '"';
  let destLoc = '"' + point2.lat + ',' + point2.lng + '"';
  getRouteDetails(Platform.OS, startLoc, destLoc).then((details) => {
    setArrivalTime(details.duration ? parseFloat(details.duration / 60).toFixed(0) : 0);
    let points = Polyline.decode(details.polylinePoints);
    let coords = points.map((point, index) => {
      return {
        latitude: point[0],
        longitude: point[1]
      }
    })
    setLiveRouteCoords(coords);
    mapRef.current.fitToCoordinates([{
      latitude: point1.lat,
      longitude: point1.lng
    }, {
      latitude: point2.lat,
      longitude: point2.lng
    }], {
      edgePadding: {
        top: 40,
        right: 40,
        bottom: 40,
        left: 40
      },
      animated: true,
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: I want to reduce the number of requests Directions AP